# How do I manually adjust parenlevel in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

Some stylesheets have a policy of alternating between parentheses and brackets when nesting parenthetical material in footnote citations.

To this end, `biblatex` has a module `parentracker` to keep track of the `parenlevel`.

e.g.

```
\footnote{See, e.g., \emph{Sonnet 18} \parencite[48]{ham12sha}.}
```

> 1. See, e.g., *Sonnet 18* (Paul Hammond, ed., *Shakespeare’s Sonnets: An Original-Spelling Text* [Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2012], 48).

When I create a \footnote that includes manual parentheses, `biblatex` isn't aware of this and cheerfully reproduces the current `parenlevel`.

```
\footnote{Here I make an insightful comment (Dio Cassius, \emph{Roman History}, ch. 60.19 \parencite[414–16]{fos24dio}).}
```

> 1. Here I make an insightful comment (Dio Cassius, *Roman History*, ch. 60.19 (Herbert Baldwin Foster, ed., *Dio’s* Roman History, trans. Earnest Cary [London: Heinemann, 1924], 414–16)).

How can I manually toggle the `parenlevel` after typing an opening parenthesis so the second set of parentheses shows up as square brackets (and the third as parentheses)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the literal `(` and `)` in your note with `\bibopenparen` and `\bibcloseparen`. Make sure they are balanced!

```
\footnote{Here I make an insightful comment 
          \bibopenparen 
          Dio Cassius, \emph{Roman History}, ch. 60.19 
          \parencite[414–16]{fos24dio}%
          \bibcloseparen.}
```

Comment: `\mkbibparens` as in `\footnote{Here I make an insightful comment \mkbibparens{Dio Cassius, \emph{Roman History}, ch. 60.19  \parencite[414–16]{cicero}}.}` might be even nicer.

Comment: Plus, do not forget to add `%` after the `\parencite` command to avoid those pesky spurious whitespaces.

Comment: @moewe Thanks. I've edited the code to add the `%`. Whether `\mkbibparens` is nicer seems to me a matter of taste, but either works.